# bit padding in structure within union

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2010. here in structure at bit position 16 and 23,24 extra bit (zero) is being added. i need to read the data from union variable FRAME.
    I need suggestion how to remove those extra bits.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
#pragma once


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
#pragma pack(1)
    typedef struct /* __declspec(align(1)) */ STTCADispCtrl
    {
        unsigned char label;
        unsigned char sdi : 2;
        unsigned char ia : 1;
        unsigned char As : 2;
        unsigned char Att : 1;
        unsigned char Dtif : 1;
        unsigned char Ac : 2;
        unsigned char Mil : 3;
        unsigned char R8 : 1;
        unsigned long R0to7 : 8;
        unsigned char ssm : 2;
        unsigned char parity : 1;
    }ST_TCAS_MODE_DISP_CTRL;


    typedef union FrameData
    {
        unsigned long FRAME;
        ST_TCAS_MODE_DISP_CTRL              tcas_Disp_ctrl;
    }FRAME_DATA;

    unsigned long fout;
    unsigned int size = 0;
    FRAME_DATA    Fdata;
    Fdata = { 0 };


    size = sizeof(Fdata.tcas_Disp_ctrl);

    cout << size << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the order of the bitfield members fixed, it can't be changed? The problem is that you have e.g. `Ac` which spans a byte boundary. Then you have a `long` bitfield member, which will align it on the natural boundary for `long`. If you reorder the members, and change the `R0to7` member to an `unsigned char` as well you will not have padding issues

Comment: That's because you are packing the structure to 1 byte boundary. `label` will occupy 8 bits. After `unsigned char Att : 1;` 7 bits are allocated, `unsigned char Ac : 2;` needs 2 bit space, however, only 1 bit is available. Hence, one bit will be padded and these 2 bits will be allocated to the next byte boundary. Same explanation goes for bits 23 and 24.

Comment: `unsigned long R0to7 : 8;` Que? What's this supposed to mean? Why long? Why not a simple char?

Comment: Why not always using long instead of char ?  This would fix the problem with 1 bit left in byte but 2 needed. It should not allocate more memory. than using chars in total the union must be a long anyway because of FRAME

Comment: We are using this frame for Arinc 429 transmission so bit field members cannot be changed. Unsigned long has been changed to unsigned char and the issue is still existing. Is there a solution to pack the structure without changing bit field members.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to byte-align the structure?
Why do you have to use this particular structure? If the frame fits in 32-bits, I don't see why you'd need to.